# Google+ Domains API v1. Error 403 "Access not configured"

Tags: api, google-plus

I am starting to use the google+ API, but I am getting problems authenticating, even in the Google Playground.

I want to do a very easy thing, which is get the circled people of my user, so, I use the scopes:

/auth/plus.circles.read
/auth/plus.me

And I request with:

https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles

In both Google PlayGround, and in the API page https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/list which allows you to test it, both of them give me the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

It is strange, because it says that I my access is not configured, but it should be. I even try adding all the scopes of google+ domain API...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you enabled Google+ Api in https://code.google.com/apis/console/?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kind of what Akash said - check the API is enabled. The Google+ domains API is different than the main Google+ API, so you'll need to ensure both are enabled:

[image: Enabling an API in the Google Cloud Console]

Also make sure that the user you're testing with is a member of the domain, and you have appropriate permissions. This isn't an API for general functionality - its specifically for managing the Google+ accounts for users within a Google Apps for Business domain, so you might have trouble if you're testing it with a @gmail.com user or similar.

Comment: I already did it, but the point is that even in Google PlayGround is not working neither... I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong, because makes not sense that the Playground does not work...

Answer (score 3):

As Ian said, you need to enable the Google+ Domains API in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). However, to user the Google+ Domains API, you do not need the Google+ API enabled, as well. These are two distinct services.

Furthermore, to make a request, the request must be authenticated. This means that you either need to make the requests using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/) or through [domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation). For the Google Playground, you should be able to use OAuth within the playground.

Also, as Ian said, the Google+ Domains API only works for a domain, so make sure that you are testing against a domain that you have access to for OAuth calls, or admin rights to for delegation calls.

Comment: Thank you Soooo much Joanna... Really,you make my day :)))))) i forget to play with OAuth 2.0 Playground ;)