# Unable to access Google Plus API in browser

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am working on to display wall posts (Stream) data using Google Plus API.
I have valid Client ID + API_KEY.

I am able to get response from Google Plus cloud console. i.e. by executing method I get something like:

> Request
> GET [https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/myuserid/activities/public?maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/myuserid/activities/public?maxResults=5&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)
> X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

> Response
> 200 OK

- Show headers -

```
 {
    "kind": "plus#activityFeed",
    "etag": "\"Mwea3qudNDf-hWWlPWi3n-YrU1Q/ovxXa0lmTRbwzkDa9o_iJ2pdFBs\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAIQgIi2z8bDugIgASgB",
    "title": "Google+ List of Activities for Collection PUBLIC",
    "updated": "2013-11-01T12:07:44.665Z",
    "items": [
    {
    "kind": "plus#activity",
    "etag": "\"Mwea3qudNDf-hWWlPWi3n-YrU1Q/JdSanh1QlMQ72Ubbabsiz2rP4B8\"",
     "published": "2013-11-01T12:07:44.665Z",
    "updated": "2013-11-01T12:07:44.665Z",
    "id": "id",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/userid/posts/bYSPSVjXCXL",
    "actor": {
    "id": "116100754354787768146",
    "displayName": "name",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/userid",
    "image": {
    "url": "someurl"
    }
    },
    "verb": "post",
    "object": {
    "objectType": "note",
    "content": "",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/userid/posts/bYSPSVjXCXL",
    "replies": {
    "totalItems": 1,
    "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13xulwx3qjuxnkii04cjpsqgsjlyp2j23o/comments"
    },
    }
```

Seems good till now.. but, when I use Request URL i.e. [https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/myuserid/activities/public?maxResults=5&key={MY_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/myuserid/activities/public?maxResults=5&key=%7BMY_API_KEY%7D) I got something from browser like this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Where I am going wrong? How to get correct response from Browser, as I want to parse them and use these data in my Application?

**NOTE: Google + API is ON.**

Comment: Im having the same problem have u got something working? some example code?

Comment: no,not yet.i have check CLIENT_ID + API_KEY .there is no problem with that.if you working with PHP aur JAVA you have to register your app in Google App Engine.(Answer from google + developer's community) . There should be some problem with OAuth 2.0 Authentication.i am working on that.you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352669/google-domains-api-v1-error-403-access-not-configured answer by Joanna. Goood Luck !!

Comment: Finally,i ended up using OAuth2.0 Playground :))

Answer (score 2):

Are you making sure that you have replaced {MY_API_KEY} with the API key that you have generated using the Cloud Console?

Comment: If i put wrong key error code would be 400 and message would be "Bad request",So.there isn't any problem with API_key i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Browser Key? It works OK for me.
[image]

Comment: Their wasn't problem with API_KEY.
The part of OAuth2.0 was missing.Resolve the issue yesterday.
BTW,what is the difference between Server key and Browser key ?! , just for knowledge.

Comment: Browser key works for all browsers, including mobile browsers as well.
But key for other platform for example android can only work in the platform itself.

Comment: So Browser key is Suggested to use in our iPhone/Android App.Right ?!

Comment: Eh, the advantage to using a server key is that it allows you to whitelist IP addresses. So if you want to white list some IP addresses you can do so by generating a server key.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue, could you post the solution that worked for you, as an answer so that other people who have the same problem can learn from it?