# Using Google+ API to get public info

Tags: android, api, google-plus

im trying to make an android APP that gets info from a Google+ page, i want to get user posts to show in my app.

Google+ API has 2 types of authentication, i can see a public page without logging o my account so i think i only need a API Key for android APPS.

I´ve created a new API Proyect on the Google API Console, put my package name and SHA1 of my debug key to get the API Key.

But when trying to get JSON data im getting problems, im using this URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111770923050795384853?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

It works fine on the google tester (bottom of the api doc page), but on the browser it returns:

```
   {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

I googled about and only found that i need to set ON the Google+ API on the console, but that was already done.

On my Android APP, with this simple code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/118051310819094153327?key={API_KEY}");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

I get FileNotFound Exception on url.openStream(), i think this is because of the 403 error returned by the server.

I only need to get data posted by a public user profile, what i can easily see on my browser, so i dont need to use OAuth.

Have someone used Google + API for this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

EDIT: Same problem here
[Unable to access Google Plus API in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741221/unable-to-access-google-plus-api-in-browser?rq=1)

Comment: You are replacing {API_KEY} with the key that you generated right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it works Ok for me. 
When I turn off Google + API in on the console, the error you meet recurs.

The error means your key is correct, but the project with this key are not open for Google+ API.

So is the key you are using the one registered with Google API open?[image]

Comment: I was using the Android Key not Browser Key, i created a new Browser APP and i works fine with browser key.

Comment: I was wondering how to set the allowed referrers to all, turns out I just need to leave it blank.